# Base Detection Algorithm

Tags: programming, equities, technical-analysis

is there any open source / commercial Java/C#/any language that has algorithm to detect base formation ?, see the base formation before Buy Point below.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Are you referring to the black resistance line, the SMA(50) or am I missing something completely? There are some TA packages in Python which might do what you want. The first is the [Technical analysis library in Python](https://technical-analysis-library-in-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ta.html#momentum-indicators) and the other is the [TA-lib](http://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/doc_index.html). Take a look at the documentation, and try to find their Github pages, if you want to look at the source code :-)

Comment: Is it simply an upside breakout from a 30 day channel ? (i.e price went above highest high of last 30 days?). That would be easy to implement. Optionally you can require that the channel be sufficiently narrow (as a percentage of stock price) i.e. highest high and lowest low close together.

Comment: yes, channel that gets narrower and then breakout of black resistance line.
it is https://tradingsim.com/blog/volatility-contraction-pattern/

it might be N arbitrary days @noob2